# How do i make my discord bot write like this box?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been looking for some discord bots. These days, i found one that make this:

[image]

I'll explain because the bot it's in Portuguese.

In the yellow part, the bot says: "Sugested by @member 
In the light blue, the bot says the command to the members, (it's a bot that rewrite the messages, 
example: *!sugest I would like marshmallows*.) 
In the dark blue, the bod auto add some roles.

---

***How do i make my discord bot write in a "box" like that ?***

Answer (score 1):

Those are called Discord embeds. Take a look at the example in their documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/embed

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor("YELLOW")
.setTitle(`Suggested by <@${message.author.id)>`)
.setDescription("``TEXT GOES HERE``")
.setFooter("!sugest I would like marshmallows.")

message.channel.send(Embed)
message.react('');
message.react('');
```

The Embed you are trying to copy is probably from a Starboard bot so you'll need some more coding to get it to send a message to a specific channel